# Can Anybody tell me whats wrong with my flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart

i was following a tutorial on flutter. I wrote the same code as he did in his video but when i wrote the code in my IDE it showed errors as shown in picture.

[image: errors]

the code i wrote

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp() as Widget
  );


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget; {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
}
```

any body pls help

i tried quick fixes that VScode was suggesting me but nothing helped.
tried these commands

```
flutter clean
```

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: remove extra } from the last line of your code

Comment: @Mearaj nothing happened bro, error is still

Comment: import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(
      MyApp() as Widget
  );
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment: Copy the above code, there were some syntax errors in your code.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mearaj/35fc428f065cb5365ddc25b03af08349

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a semicolon `;` after the class name which is wrong, and the class should be outside the main function.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp() as Widget
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, bro, it is now fixed, I am a beginner and that's why i was dumb